# sql select info per day per team

Tags: sql

I need to select some info from the DB, per day and per team. I want to see how many items were bought per day, for each team. For example, if there were 6 items bought in 2012-11-21, I want my results to show: team 1 bought 3 items, team 2 - 2 items and the last team 1 item. I can get the info for one team, using this:

```
select count(CONVERT(date, getdate())) as Team1
from items
where team = 1
group by CONVERT(date, getdate())
```

But I am not sure how can I get the info I need, for all the teams.

**EDIT**

I need the results to be something like this:

```
Date      |Team1   | Team2   | Team3  
2012-11-21|2 items | 3 items | 0 items
```

And my table structure is something like this: `Date, Product, Price, Team`.

Comment: You should always attach table structure and database system if you want adequate answers

Comment: where is a date in your result? you want date as parameter?

Comment: Are or will be there more teams or just 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need here, is `PIVOT` your table like so:

```
SELECT 
  Date,
  SUM(CASE WHEN team = 'team1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'team1',
  SUM(CASE WHEN team = 'team2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'team2',
  SUM(CASE WHEN team = 'team3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'team3'
FROM Tablename
GROUP BY date;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `GROUP BY` team and date.

```
SELECT datecol, team, COUNT(*)
FROM items
GROUP BY datecol, team
```

Based on your updated requirement and not knowing what your DBMS is:

```
SELECT a.datecol AS 'Date',
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM items WHERE datecol = a.datecol AND team = '1') AS 'Team1',
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM items WHERE datecol = a.datecol AND team = '2') AS 'Team2',
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM items WHERE datecol = a.datecol AND team = '3') AS 'Team3'
FROM items a
GROUP BY a.datecol
```